# Rails not running migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm experiencing a really strange issue where rails won't execute migrations on my machine. I'm using Rails 4.2.5, Ruby 2.3.1p112, and Postgres 9.5.3 on OS X 10.11.6.

The database creates/migrates and functions properly at Heroku and on another Mac with the same versions of everything.

If I import the database from Heroku or the other machine I get a pending migration error when running `rails s`, even when I'm on the same exact source version.

Running a `db:schema` tells me:

```
You have 23 pending migrations:
  20160627035230 DeviseCreateUsers
  20160627035442 CreatePages
  20160627055031 AddHeroToPages
  20160627061237 AddAdministratorToUser
  20160627061943 AddNameToUser
  20160628042547 CreateSchools
  20160628042702 CreateLicenses
  20160628042841 JoinUsersAndSchools
  20160628043323 AddJoinCodeToSchools
  20160630012028 AddExpiryToLicenses
  20160630024743 CreatePurchases
  20160630043846 AddOmniauthToUsers
  20160704003626 CreateMyIndustries
  20160704010403 CreateMyCareers
  20160704013913 CreateMyQuestions
  20160704074916 AlterMyQuestionsDrop
  20160704075947 AlterMyQuestionsChange
  20160705071702 CreateUserAttributes
  20160710235339 CreateAccessabilities
  20160711000000 AddToAccessabilities
  20160711044815 CreateMedia
  20160711045327 AddLocaleToMedium
  20160814010549 CreateInvoices
Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
```

Running the migration then tells me:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

Listing tables in psql only shows the schema_migrations:

```
20:09 $ rails db
psql (9.5.3)
Type "help" for help.

mytalents_development=# \dt
                  List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  |     Owner      
--------+-------------------+-------+----------------
 public | schema_migrations | table | aidancornelius
(1 row)

mytalents_development=#
```

I also seem to get strange errors with `db:migrate:up`

```
20:11 $ rake db:migrate:up
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError: 

No migration with version number 0

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:939:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:834:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:82:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:up
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Does anyone have any insight about what might be going on here? Other projects in Rails 4 and Rails 5 work on this machine, but this one just won't.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: `rake db:migrate:up` needs a `version` number specified like in your case you can do `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20160627035230`

Answer (score 2):

I bet this is an issue with Postgres Schemas. I had similar problem, but in my case migrations were working on my local machine and not on Heroku. It was caused by different settings to schema_search_path. On my local machine it was `'"$user",public'` but `'"$user", public'"` on Heroku and this additional space was breaking everything.

In your case you need to check what is your `schema_search_path` on your machine. Maybe you should set it to just "public" in database.yml file. You can check it with `SHOW search_path` query.

Comment: That's exactly right. The old Rails code splits the result of `show search_path` on `,`, which breaks with the new default value. The workaround is to place the following in the connection settings in `database.yml`: `schema_search_path: '"$user",public'`

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of rails migration files (and migration process) is the most important part, so you can try to migrate the first migration file using:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=20160627035230
```

then use just `db:migrate` or `db:migrate Version=20160814010549`